# Applying UDT on Spring Data

Tags: java, cassandra, spring-data

I have created custom defined types in cassandra and I'm trying to insert the data using spring. At first i thought using entity like this would work:

```
@PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "appid", ordinal = 0, type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
private String appid;
@PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "event", ordinal = 1, type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED, ordering = Ordering.ASCENDING)
private String event;
@PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "date", ordinal = 2, type = PrimaryKeyType.CLUSTERED, ordering = Ordering.DESCENDING)
private Date date;
@PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "userid", ordinal = 3, type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
private String userid;
@Column (name = "items")
@Frozen
private Map<CassandraEventParamModel,CassandraEventStatsModel> items;
```

And created a UDT in java like this (param from create type):

```
@UDT(keyspace = "ms_analytics", name = "param")
public class CassandraEventParamModel {
    @Field(name = "key")
    public String key;
    @Field(name = "value")
    public String value;
```

but I kept getting an error which says

```
 Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.VerifierMappingExceptions:
Cassandra entities must have the @Table, @Persistent or @PrimaryKeyClass Annotation
```

I wonder what is the proper way to deliver data using spring-data into cassandra.

Thanks